# Unity Android IAP "Purchase failed because Purchasing was not initialized correctly"

Tags: unity, android, in-app-purchase

**What I have**

IAP button is working perfectly in unity editor. After purchasing, i'm getting debug message "ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: 'full_version'" . **But the button does nothing when I try to make a purchase on the device.**

Don't have any errors when purchasing product in editor

**What have i done so far**

Automatically initialize UnityPurchasing checkbox is switched ON [image: IAP catalog unity]

1. I've checked that the product ID, and price are the same in unity and Play console
2. My IAP product is showing active in play console
   [image: Play console IAP]
3. setup the Codeless IAP like this
   [image: unity IAP component]

**LogCat error when I press the button on the device**

```
2022-03-14 20:08:18.244 9293-9334/? E/Unity: Purchase failed because Purchasing was not initialized correctly
    UnityEngine.Purchasing.CodelessIAPStoreListener:InitiatePurchase(String)
    UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
    UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
```

IAP script

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing; //библиотека с покупками, будет доступна когда активируем сервисы

public class IAP : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener //для получения сообщений из Unity Purchasing
{
   

    private static IStoreController m_StoreController;          //доступ к системе Unity Purchasing
    private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider; // подсистемы закупок для конкретных магазинов

    public static string fullVersion = "full_version";


    void Start()
    {
        if (m_StoreController == null) //если еще не инициализаровали систему Unity Purchasing, тогда инициализируем
        {
            InitializePurchasing();
        }

    }

    public void InitializePurchasing()
    {
        if (IsInitialized()) //если уже подключены к системе - выходим из функции
        {
            return;
        }

        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

        builder.AddProduct(fullVersion, ProductType.NonConsumable);


        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }

    public void Buy_full_version()
    {
        BuyProductID(fullVersion);
    }

    

    void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        if (IsInitialized()) //если покупка инициализирована 
        {
            Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId); //находим продукт покупки 

            if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase) //если продукт найдет и готов для продажи
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));
                m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product); //покупаем
                
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
        }
    }

    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) //контроль покупок
    {
        


        

         if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, fullVersion, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));

            //действия при покупке
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("full_version") == false)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("full_version", 1);

            }
            
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        }

        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }

    public void RestorePurchases() //Восстановление покупок (только для Apple). У гугл это автоматический процесс.
    {
        if (!IsInitialized())
        {
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not initialized.");
            return;
        }

        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer) //если запущенно на эпл устройстве
        {
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases started ...");

            var apple = m_StoreExtensionProvider.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();

            apple.RestoreTransactions((result) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("RestorePurchases continuing: " + result + ". If no further messages, no purchases available to restore.");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not supported on this platform. Current = " + Application.platform);
        }
    }



    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnInitialized: PASS");
        m_StoreController = controller;
        m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
    }

    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
        return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
    }

    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
    }

    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{0}', PurchaseFailureReason: {1}", product.definition.storeSpecificId, failureReason));
    }



}
```

The problem is that I don't understand what this error means, and subsequently how to solve it. Hoping for your help

Answer (score 1):

In my case activating/initializing of IAP in `Project Settings->Services->In-app purchasing` helped me. Hope this will be helpful for you too.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it showed the steps for activating and initializing IAP.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the event trigger added to the button component itself (PlayButtonSound();)

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained how this solves the problem.